# Parse.com: generate statistics out of a large set of data

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, backend

I'm a video game developer and I use Parse.com for my games. Thanks to it I save players scores and game durations. At the end of every game session I show community statistics to let player see where his score fits among community scores.

Something looking like this:
[image]

As I'm no backend expert, and as I never though one of my mini games would have to deal with a big amount of data, I naively computed these statistics using a cloud code (feature provided by Parse.com) anylizing every score entry and generating a chart made of 40 points.

So far I extracted every score from the Parse.com database and extracted the following data:

- max_score (int): the max score in the set;
- points (string): 40 points from 0 to 1, comma separated, describing the actual chart;
- entry_count (int): the number of entries in the database;
- medium (float): the medium score of the set;

**EDIT**

points string is the most important here. It's a string looking like :

```
0.4147,0.286,0.2179,0.1463,0.1106,0.0819,0.0676,0.0458,0.0363,0.0264,0.0206,0.014,0.0096,0.008,0.0063,0.0042,0.0027,0.0025,0.0018,0.0013,0.0008,0.0008,0.0004,0.0005,0.0003,0.0002,0.0002,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Each number represents a point of the statistics. The more games with the same score, higher the point number will be. The first point represents scores close to 0 and the last point represents scores close to max_score. Numbers are from 0 to 1. So if 90% of the scores are 0 (or almost), the first number in the string will be 0.9...

**/EDIT**

The problem is the number of games played so far (more than 500K games). Which means that the script in charge of computing statistics points has to deal with 500K+ scores which is WAY higher than the actual JavaScript array limitation.

I know it's probably a basic problem for any backend specialist but I can't find a clever solution to this. I don't know how to generate statistics out of so much data entries using Cloud Code written in JavaScript in Parse.com.

Any help or guidance would be apprecitated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on having a popular app.  The row count is a low cost operation, just do (new Parse.Query("MyTable")).count().  The way to do summary stats is to keep a running max and average in a single row in their own table.  You can compute an incremental average with a count, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing).  The gist is:

```
newAve = oldAve + (newScore-oldAverage)/count
```

The max is even simpler:

```
newMax = (newScore>oldMax)? newScore : oldMax;
```

Not sure I understand what the `points` refers to in your question, but hopefully you can extend the ideas here.

**EDIT**

I think I understand the points data to be a distribution of scores.  It sounds like you bin the score into 40 categories (probably by rounding), and then count the number of scores achieved in each bin.  If I'm right, this, too, can be handled with an additional summary representation:  Add a table with a column that represents the bin (say an int, 0..40), and an int column that represents the number of scores achieved in that bin.  That whole table 40*2ints can be easily read into memory and manipulated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the main problem is about computing points. On the image you can see a chart made of 40 points. The higher the point is (closer to 1.0) the more games with that score have been played. Then if 90% of the games have a score close to 150 and the max score is 300, then the points at the center of the chart will have a value of 0.9.
Also, chart left side is score of 0, and right side is the max score. Is it more clear now?

Comment: This is a simple idea but it should work. Thanks for your help.